# Flutter | How to change orientation when redirect to another page

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, flutter-dependencies

Here i am getting one issue let me explain to you. (Ex) - I've one page which is by default portrait up and when I redirect to another page it needs to be landscape. I've achieved this landscape using this  `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);` so when I get back to the first page it needs to be portrait but it remains the same as landscape.

i am using this snippet for landscape this page   `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);`
in the `dispose` method of your second page which is landscape.

Answer (score 2):

In the first page of build method, you need to write first line before return `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);`.
In the second page of build method, you need to write first line before return `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);`.
**Understanding**
Whlex going back to first page, build method will get called, and as orientation is set to portraitUp there it will work.
This works for me.

Comment: yes but instead of this solution its better to dispose the orientation

Comment: I guess it is the same thing for setting the orientation in dispose method of the second screen or build method in the first screen. The method will get called once in both cases. Writing this line does not dispose of any resources though. The benefits of this implementation would be only consistency, nothing else.

Comment: ive tried your method as well. but now I am facing issue is on my first page I've written portrait up and then redirected to second page then I've written landscape left but it will blink the page with landscape and then get back to it original

Comment: can you please help me with this

Comment: I guess this is a bug while using Navigator.push method.. This works perfectly while using Navigator pushReplacednmethod... Once I get this issue get solved from the community, I will comment here. Thanks!

Comment: Don't have exactly. however you can join me on LinkedIn..https://www.linkedin.com/in/sanketvekariya